# What is the number of possible seating arrangements?

Tags: combinatorics

I have an exercise to do: How many possibilities for placing 12 apostles if it is important who is sitting next to who but it is not important from which side?

Answer possibilities:

a) [image]

b) [image]

c) [image]

d) [image]

It is possible that more than one option is correct and also that not any option is correct.
In my opinion the good answer is **d**, but on my class some people have different opinions. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the right place for questions about religion

Comment: Hehe. God will be glad for our attentione to his things :)

Comment: So what data do you have on who is sitting next to who, and are they in a line or in a circle?

Comment: If someone has this same neighbours (no matter if A person is sitting on the right side and B person is sitting on the left or B person is sitting on the right side and A person is sitting on the left) we have situation wchih should be counted only one time. They are in a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine for a moment that the apostles are just standing in a line. There would be $12!$ ways to arrange them. They are actually in a cycle, however, and any of the $12$ rotations of that cycle counts as the same arrangement for us. Moreover, flipping the cycle also counts as the same cycle for us. Dividing out the redundancies gives
$$
\frac{12!}{12 \cdot 2} = \frac{11!}{2}.
$$

Comment: I know what you meant. Thank you.